# Linux kernel module timer interrupt frequency?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, kernel, raspberry-pi3

I'm just evaluating the possibilities of a Raspberry Pi and therefore have a (may be stupid) question just to understand if it is possible what I'm thinking about.

I want to use the GPIOs of the Pi with some additional hardware and do some bit-banging with it. For this I need quite a fast timer. The SoC with its >1GHz clock and the available hardware timers are absolutely capable of providing the related timer frequency.

But: I want to use the Pi with a Linux system and the timer interrupt out of a kernel module. So my question is: is there a possibility to set up a kernel-internal timer of e.g. 2 MHz? Is the Kernel capable of doing this? Or is one of the hardware timers freely available and can be used for this job?

Comment: Please `cat /proc/timer_list`. This virtual file lists all available frequencies on the hardware. According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/14945083/5509575, the maximum rate is 1000Hz or 0.001MHz, but depending on the file maybe you can up the timer speed. Also see here for a solution for speeding up the latency https://medium.com/@metebalci/latency-of-raspberry-pi-3-on-standard-and-real-time-linux-4-9-kernel-2d9c20704495

Comment: @Penn This lists some (unused) clocks/timers in range of a few nsec, so this would be suitable. But can they be used out of a kernel module to trigger an interrupt serive routine regularly?

Comment: On my system, the scheduler timer interrupt alone causes 4us delay (measured with `perf record -e irq:softirq_entry -e irq:softirq_exit`.. not sure how much of that is caused by 'perf', though). I doubt that you get 500ns latency on Pi with linux. I would run a loop and regularly check the CPU cycle counter to see when the 500ns are elapsed.

Comment: Yes, the link to medium shows that there is a high latency with the default kernel. However, you could try using a realtime kernel, or building with HZ= the one over the number of seconds (not ns)

Comment: Johannes Schaub this sounds like a good idea. But: wouldn't this permanent loop stall the complete kernel/system? Or is it possible to force one kernel module to run on one specific core of the CPU exclusively? I know one can keep away all load from a core with the isolcpu kernel parameter...

Comment: @MarcvanderMeer linux has kernel threads, maybe that's an option.